# Regular expression to match phrase with unicode character

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to parse the indicated range in the following sentence with regular expressions in Python (`re` package) but have had no luck so far:

```
body = 'Adulticides are modelled by increasing the mosquito mortality rate [9] , [20] – [22] .'
```

I'm trying to match

`[20] – [22]`

where the problem appears to be that the hyphen is not the usual `-` but some unicode hyphen `–`.

The closest I get to matching the first half of this range is this:

```
m = re.findall(r'\[20\] ', body)
```

How would you match the entire range?

Comment: Cant you just copy and paste the hyphen into your regex? \[20\]\s(–|-)\s\[22\]

Edit: For some reason my escaping of the brackets is not showing in the comments.

Comment: @Martyn Yes, that's another option. Btw, use backticks for code formatting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use it with unicode flag like this:

```
m = re.findall(r'\[\d+\] – \[\d+\]', body, re.UNICODE)
```

This should return `[20] – [22]` from the string you`ve specified.